# Purposely failing Low-Level Call

Tags: solidity, ether, gas, security, vulnerability

Does this code below have a vulnerability?

```
burnAddress.call.value(msg.value)("");                                             
//update state
```

burn Address is a trusted contract, which cannot purposely fail: I was wondering if you can make it fail by for example not sending enough gas, or spamming other calls to burnAddress (DDOS)? Since the low-level call is unchecked this would lead to bad sideeffects. I know that this is always supposed to be checked after execution.